# Unable to view asset image file in Gallery via cwac-provider

Tags: android, image, android-intent, commonsware-cwac

I want to open an image present in my app's assets with any available image viewer in the device. Using cwac-provider library, I have been **able to do the same for some .pps files in assets without a trouble** but, the images don't quite work as needed. I have looked up the demo and nearly all of the [documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) available. I even searched the web & SO questions but didn't really get a fix.

I'm **targeting API 26**.

Here's how I've set up the provider.

### AndroidManifest

```
<provider
        android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider"
        android:authorities="com.justsomeproj.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.provider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/asset_file_meta" />
    </provider>
```

### asset_file_meta

```
<paths>
    <asset
        name="gallery_a"
        path="gallery/a" />
    <asset
        name="gallery_b"
        path="gallery/b" />
    ...
</paths>
```

### FileProvider

```
public class FileProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITY =
            "com.justsomeproj.provider";
    private static final Uri PROVIDER =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);

    public static Uri buildUri(String path, String fileName) {
        return (PROVIDER
                .buildUpon()
                .appendPath(StreamProvider.getUriPrefix(AUTHORITY))
                .appendPath(path).appendPath(fileName)
                .build());
    }

    public static boolean isIntentResolvable(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        return intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null;
    }

}
```

### Intent call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.buildUri(path, fileName));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (FileProvider.isIntentResolvable(this, intent))
            startActivity(intent);
```

### The issue

So, on intent execution, the gallery does show up but with a blank preview and "No thumbnail" message on it. I tried multiple gallery apps but faced the same results and saw similar or same errors in logcat.

Even though they fail to load the thumbnail, they do receive the file.
I say this because, while on the blank preview in the Gallery apps, if I try to view file information, it does show correct info about the file. Trying to 'share' the image from the same screen also works and the next app(used to share) gets the image file without issues.
The Google Photos app, however, shows the image flawlessly. Weird.

The issue occurs on API 21, 25, 26 and most likely on others in between these too(untested).

### URI generated

```
content://com.justsomeproj.provider/30b6ac14-6bec-4e54-a1d3-445367f69ccc/gallery_a/image1.jpeg
```

### Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file
```

### Logcat

```
09-21 10:21:16.453 1214-2098/? I/PackageManager: Setting last chosen activity com.android.gallery3d/.app.GalleryActivity for user 0:
09-21 10:21:16.453 1214-2098/? I/PackageManager:   Action: "android.intent.action.VIEW"
09-21 10:21:16.453 1214-2098/? I/PackageManager:   Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
09-21 10:21:16.453 1214-2098/? I/PackageManager:   Type: "image/jpeg"
09-21 10:21:16.453 1214-2098/? I/PackageManager:   AutoVerify=false
09-21 10:21:16.461 1214-2677/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.justsomeproj.provider/30b6ac14-6bec-4e54-a1d3-445367f69ccc/gallery_a/image1.jpeg flg=0x3000001 cmp=com.android.gallery3d/.app.GalleryActivity} from uid 10233 on display 0
09-21 10:21:16.675 14814-14814/? V/StateManager: startState class com.android.gallery3d.app.SinglePhotoPage
09-21 10:21:16.727 14814-15533/? W/UriImage: fail to open: content://com.justsomeproj.provider/30b6ac14-6bec-4e54-a1d3-445367f69ccc/gallery_a/image1.jpeg
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file
                                                 at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:856)
                                                 at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:793)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.openOrDownloadInner(UriImage.java:108)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.openFileOrDownloadTempFile(UriImage.java:83)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.prepareInputFile(UriImage.java:170)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.-wrap0(UriImage.java)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage$RegionDecoderJob.run(UriImage.java:185)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage$RegionDecoderJob.run(UriImage.java:176)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:133)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                 at com.android.gallery3d.util.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:44)
09-21 10:21:16.727 14814-15533/? W/SinglePhotoDataAdapter: fail to get region decoder, try to request thumb image
09-21 10:21:16.739 14814-14814/? W/SinglePhotoDataAdapter: fail to decode thumb
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                               at com.android.gallery3d.app.SinglePhotoDataAdapter.onDecodeThumbComplete(SinglePhotoDataAdapter.java:151)
                                                               at com.android.gallery3d.app.SinglePhotoDataAdapter.-wrap1(SinglePhotoDataAdapter.java)
                                                               at com.android.gallery3d.app.SinglePhotoDataAdapter$3.handleMessage(SinglePhotoDataAdapter.java:70)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at com.android.gallery3d.ui.SynchronizedHandler.dispatchMessage(SynchronizedHandler.java:36)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

The logcat is from a physical API 25 device.

I have tried the suggestions in the documentation about supporting legacy apps without any success.
I also tried some tweaks to the intent, no joy there either.

@CommonsWare I'm kinda stuck with this so seeking suggestions. What am I missing?

**Is my intent fine?

Why doesn't it work?

Why Google Photos app works well?

Is it an issue in the gallery apps or the library?

Is there a workaround?**

At the moment I'm thinking of writing the file to cache and try viewing via Android's FileProvider(instead of cwac-provider's StreamProvider) to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my intent fine?

I cannot answer that, as I do not know the contents of your `assets/` directory in your project. However, if anything can read the `Uri`, then the `Uri` is fine. The rest of your `Intent` seems fine.

> Why doesn't it work?

Perhaps you do not [have `noCompress` configured](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#gradle-settings), though I would expect it to fail all the time if that were the case.

Perhaps adding [the additional elements for legacy app support](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#supporting-legacy-apps) will help with compatibility with these other apps.

And I am not quite certain why you are doing any of this in the first place, versus simply displaying the image yourself in the app. Not only is there `ImageView`, but third-party library classes like `SubsamplingImageView` that offer more features (e.g., pinch-to-zoom).

> Why Google Photos app works well?

Um, because Google is teh awesome? :-)

The fact that any app can handle your `Intent` and `Uri` indicates that the `Intent` and `Uri` are fine.

> Is it an issue in the gallery apps or the library?

I have no way of knowing.

> Is there a workaround?

I suggested two (`noCompress`, legacy app support) earlier in my answer.

Comment: As I had mentioned in my question already(it isn't clear I guess), I had tried the legacy app support components but they didn't help. Also, I do have noCompress configured and functioning.
I would go ahead and display the image in my app itself, but still I guess I would really like to understand why this didn't work in first place.

Comment: @ArpitAnand: "I had tried the legacy app support components but they didn't help" -- sorry, I tend to focus on the code listings. As it stands, I do not know if you implemented those correctly. You might try creating an instrumentation test to read the contents of the `Uri` yourself, akin to how the library's own instrumentation tests work. If that works, and Google Photos works, then the problem is with the other client apps. Switching to files (whether with `FileProvider` or `StreamProvider`) may help, as streams from assets are not seekable, and the failing clients may need that.

Comment: So I tried FileProvider and it worked! 
Anyways, I'm gonna display the image within the app itself. Thanks for the tip.